# Problems with unzipping openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz

Tags: 14.04, command-line, tar, gzip

While installing openfire got an error with unzipping the downloaded file that

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

When checking file format it shows like

```
$ file openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz
openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Redownload the file and try again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open [this](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/openfire/3.10.2#package_detail_tab) site in your browser and download the Linux version again and don't use `wget`, the link on the page is a redirection. Use the [download link](http://olex.openlogic.com/package_versions/26086/download?package_version_id=103675&path=https%3A%2F%2Folex-secure.openlogic.com%2Fcontent%2Fprivate%2F5e6a6f0815e830bba705e79e4a0470fbee8a5880%2F%2Folex-secure.openlogic.com%2Fopenfire_3_10_2.tar.gz) in your browser.

The result of my test is

```
% file openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz 
openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)
```

Comment: when i tried to open openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz it look like a html page

Comment: i used this command to download the file   wget -c http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=openfire/openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz
mv download-landing.jsp\?file\=openfire%2Fopenfire_3_10_2.tar.gz openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz   when i tried to open openfire_3_10_2.tar.gz it look like a html page

Comment: Don't use `wget`. The link is redirection.

Comment: i have downloaded the file and uploaded to the server and now the file format is showing like POSIX tar archieve ,having the same problem

Comment: @BinilKt: If you have a different issue now than the one in your question, please open a [new question](/questions/ask). If it's only slightly different edit this question to reflect the changes (with the *edit* link below it).